# Rendering array elements inside an object with reactjs

Tags: javascript, reactjs

```
this.questions = [{
                "id" : 1 ,
                "question" : "question",
                "answers" : ["A","B","C","D"],
            },
            {
                "id" : 2,
                "question" : "question",
                "answers"  : ["A","B","C","D"],
            }]
```

I have an object like this. And I'm rendering these data to a table.With this code;

```
renderTable(result) {
        return (
            <table>
            <tr><td>{result.id}</td><td>{result.question}</td></tr>
            <tr><td>Answers</td>{result.answers}</td></tr>
            </table>)
    }
render() {
        return (
        <Row>           
            {this.questions.map(this.renderTable.bind(this))}
        </Row>)
    }
```

Question :

I want to render every element of answers array to different table data tags.
How can I do this ?

Regards,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use a map to iterate over answer and then dynamically create td's

```
renderTable(result) {
    return (
        <table>
        <tr><td>{result.id}</td><td>{result.question}</td></tr>
        <tr><td>Answers</td>{result.answers.map(function(value,index){
                               return(<td>{value}</td>);
         })}</tr>
        </table>)
}
render() {
    return (
    <Row>           
        {this.questions.map(function(value,index){
           this.renderTable.bind(this,value);
          });
        }
    </Row>)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
  renderTable(){
    const answers = (items) => {
      return items.map((item) => {
        return ( <td>{item}</td>)
      })
    }
    return this.questions.map((result) => {
      return (
        <table>
           <tr><td>{result.id}</td><td>{result.question}</td></tr>
           <tr><td>Answers</td>
           {this.answers(result.answers)}
           </tr>
       </table>)
      )
    })
  }
  render() {
        return (
        <Row>           
            {this.renderTable()}
        </Row>
      )
    }
```

You can do like this, using map to iterate the answers

Answer (score 0):

According to me, there is no need to create renderTable(result). I have written code below, please let me know if it helps.

```
class MyComponent extends React.Component{

render() {

    const data = [{
        "id" : 1 ,
        "question" : "question1",
        "answers" : ["A1","B1","C1","D1"],
        },
        {
        "id" : 2,
        "question" : "question2",
        "answers"  : ["A2","B2","C2","D2"],
        },
        {
        "id" : 3,
        "question" : "question3",
        "answers"  : ["A3","B3","C3","D3"],
        },
        {
        "id" : 4,
        "question" : "question4",
        "answers"  : ["A4","B4","C4","D4"],
        }];

    const listItems = data.map((row) =>
        <li>
            <table>
                <tr><td>{row.id}</td><td>{row.question}</td></tr>
                <tr><td>Answers:{row.answers}</td></tr>
            </table>
       </li>
    );

    return (
        <div>
            <ul>
                {listItems}
            </ul>
        </div>
    );
}
}
```